# TypeScript: return only a part of the interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an User interface like this

```js
interface IUser {
    name: string,
    phoneNumber: string
}
```

and a PublicUser interface like this

```
interface IPublicUser {
   name: string
}
```

What i'm trying to do it's from an object of type `IUser` return only public informations.

I tried something like this :

```
 const user: IUser = {
   name: 'Eliott',
   phoneNumber : '+1...'
}

console.log(user as unknown as  IPublicUser)
```

But always return the full user.

My temporary fix it's to create a method `toPublicJson` to return only the desired field, but it's not very good, because if my interface change I must also change this method..

Do you have some advices ?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you're going to struggle, most TypeScript type information doesn't exist at runtime, but you need it at runtime to do the above. Still, TypeScript is **incredibly** powerful, so there *may* be a way...

Comment: Interface is for type binding only. It has no relationship with object creation/manipulation. You have to add some transformation logic in a method for object manipulation.

Comment: The type declarations and so serve only for static type checking at build time, and they transpile to nothing. Your `console.log(user as unknown as  IPublicUser)` will transpile to `console.log(user)` (or whatever identifier `user` will be minified into).

Comment: Oh ok, so used a method like my `toPublicJson` is a good way to do that. Thanks guys !

Comment: @Carambar - Yup -- except it has nothing to do with JSON, so probably not that name. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript (or TypeScript) source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, actually i never work with the `PublicUser` its only to send back to the client, but you're rigth it's may be not the better name because the method doesn't return JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're obviously right about JSON being a textual notation, but `.toJSON` has a special meaning in JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev - I know, but it doesn't seem relevant here. :-) (I also **really** wish they'd picked a better name, but I wasn't in the room...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remember that TypeScript compiles to JavaScript. Statements like `variable as type` get lost in transpilation. They are just hints to the transpiler and the user, but they don't really mean anything. In the same way, interfaces are just hints and help for the compiler, by they really meant nothing at runtime.

If you want to do that, you still have to do it by hand, to create another object with the properties you want:

```
const publicUser : IPublicUser = { name: user.name };
```

Of course, you may only care about what other programmers see when dealing with your code, so, in that way, they'll just see `IPublicUser` and if they want to use a property that its not in that interface, they'll get a compiler error. But if you care about what is really happening when the code is executing, then you have to do it explicitly.